# Add LifeCycle to a tenant in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Deployed IS as Key Manager before and API Manager afterward. They share the registry and the result of this deployment order was that APILifecycle got deleted (In the carbon console under Extensions->configure->Lifecycles).
I need that lifecycle so I added it to the supertenant (via carbon console) and it went ok.
I noticed that putting the APILifeCycle.xml under /wso2-home/repository/resources/lifecycles and creating a new tenant, the file get correctly created in the GUI but since the tenant was created without the .xml in place I cannot add it now.
Unfortunately when I try to add the lifecycle to a tenant via GUI i get this error:

```
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: [2019-02-01 18:55:49,280] ERROR - ApplicationDispatcher Servlet.service() for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: java.lang.NullPointerException
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.pagination.PaginationUtils.getRowCount(PaginationUtils.java:152)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.ui.clients.LifeCycleManagementServiceClient.isLifeCycleNameInUse(LifeCycleManagementServiceClient.java:180)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.ui.clients.LifeCycleManagementServiceClient.isLifeCycleNameInUse(LifeCycleManagementServiceClient.java:167)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jsp.lcm.nameinusecheck_005flcm_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(nameinusecheck_005flcm_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:91)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.redirector.servlet.ui.filters.AllPagesFilter.doFilter(AllPagesFilter.java:156)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor.service(FilterServletAdaptor.java:37)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:57)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:63)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:52)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: [2019-02-01 18:55:49,282] ERROR - StandardWrapperValve Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /lcm/nameinusecheck_lcm_ajaxprocessor.jsp at line 24
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: 21: <%
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: 22:     String cookie = (String) session.getAttribute(ServerConstants.ADMIN_SERVICE_COOKIE);
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: 23:     LifeCycleManagementServiceClient client = new LifeCycleManagementServiceClient(cookie, config, session);
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: 24:     boolean isInUse = client.isLifeCycleNameInUse(request);
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: 25:     if (isInUse) {
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: 26:         %>----IsInUse----<%
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: 27:     }
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: Stacktrace:] with root cause
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: java.lang.NullPointerException
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.pagination.PaginationUtils.getRowCount(PaginationUtils.java:152)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.ui.clients.LifeCycleManagementServiceClient.isLifeCycleNameInUse(LifeCycleManagementServiceClient.java:180)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.governance.lcm.ui.clients.LifeCycleManagementServiceClient.isLifeCycleNameInUse(LifeCycleManagementServiceClient.java:167)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jsp.lcm.nameinusecheck_005flcm_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(nameinusecheck_005flcm_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:91)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.redirector.servlet.ui.filters.AllPagesFilter.doFilter(AllPagesFilter.java:156)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor.service(FilterServletAdaptor.java:37)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:57)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:63)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:52)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
feb 01 18:55:49 apimanager01-test wso2server.sh[26429]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I solve without deleting the tenant and recreating it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do following steps, and it works:

1. Login into super tenant carbon. And go to Main > Resources > Browse
2. Go to the _system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.governance/lifecycles
3. Try to export APILifeCycle
4. Import the above APILifeCycle into a tenant A

And then I can use the tenant A Publisher and Store

Comment: correct. You explained better than me. However, if you place APILifecycle in the supertenant, you will get it into every tenant you create afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to add the APILifecycle through the registry with the function "Add a resource". The path is
`/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.governance/lifecycles`

I still can't add any lifecycle through the GUI in the menu Extensions->lifecycles

Comment: I have the same issue, is there any solution